# Paid cash for a car, but dealer wants to change price

Tags: car

My son recently graduated from college, and he and his wife went to buy a car. They never discussed financing with the dealer. They agreed on a price, went to the bank and brought back a cashiers check for the amount.  They brought the car home, and two days later the dealership is saying that a mistake was made and the price included a discount for him being a new graduate, but only if he financed the car.

Am I wrong, or is that their problem?  He has already paid for it and taken possession.

Comment: Have they cashed the check? If so, the deal is closed.

Comment: As per the other comments/answers: What was actually signed? Did the title change hands? What's the locale (City/State/Country) as I assume different locales have different laws?

Comment: It sounds absurd. In Germany cash is always preferred and will give you a lower price. Though we don't have checks and transfer full amounts instead.

Comment: Could you please tag this with your country of origin/country in which the car was bought?

Comment: @simbabque Dealerships make money - often more than off the sale - off of financing (assuming they (or their brand) provide the financing).

Comment: I wonder if this is better served on [law.se], since it sounds like this is an issue of contract law?

Comment: Incidentally, many banks and credit unions offer check imaging when a check of yours is cashed.  I don't know if your son's bank/credit union offers the same thing, but it's worth looking into before making any decision on what to do next.

Comment: Something similar happened to an acquaintance. They told the dealer to go p** up a rope and took the car to a different dealer for scheduled maintenance.

Comment: It doesn't matter if he cashed the check. Its a legal instrument. If the check bounces, you don't get the car back, you sue for the amount of the check.

Comment: Whether or not they cashed the check is irrelevant, it's a cashiers check not a personal check. It might as well be cash.

Comment: This is a textbook example of the common dealership scam known as a "Yo-Yo Scam".

Comment: @maria make sure you update us on what your son and his wife did and how it went.

Comment: @BradleyUffner this isn't textbook yo-yoing, since there's no financing here to "fall through". The OP's son provided full payment, so the transaction *should* be complete. It's still possibly a scam, but seems much more likely that a salesperson screwed up and is under pressure to correct the mistake.

Comment: I got PTSD reading this, as similar happened to me. I agreed to a deal, signed papers. Then when I said I was paying cash the dealer tried to scuttle the deal. It took me all night to get out of there.

Comment: At best this is someone being less than smart (dealer) and at worst this is a scam. Deal has been finalized, keep the car, enjoy the price, and be prepared to retain legal counsel if need be

Comment: First of all, 95% probability that the dealership is trying the old "screw the first-time buyer who doesn't know any better" trick. 5% chance this is legit. I strongly suggest that your son retain counsel. IMO (and IANAL) your son has everything on his side - the negotiated deal, the signatures on the contract, AND the car. The dealership has...your son's inexperience. Retain the services of a good contract-law attorney, get his advice, and follow it.

Comment: This is textbook "car dealerships are the worst". If papers were signed, I'd start by saying "we already signed and paid, sorry". If they push back, then talk to a lawyer and CC everything to your state's DA (assuming you are in the US). Or--if they took your money, and you have the car and title, then I'd do nothing. *if* they come after you later with a lawyer, then go ahead and get a lawyer.

Comment: @simbabque, dealerships make more money from financing either because they do it themselves and receive interest payments, or because another party finances and gives them a kickback for their business. It is not uncommon for them to offer low prices to hook buyers, because they know that one of these other two ways will make up the difference.

Comment: @pauld as I said, in Germany that's the opposite because they prefer to get the money quickly and get rid of a car. Probably in the US that's way different. Other laws, other banking, other taxes. :)

Comment: You are certainly not wrong. However, I could see the decision having to go to arbitration. Another less painful approach would be to just take the financing deal and immediately payoff the load provided there are no extra fees or penalty for early payoff.

Comment: @PaulDraper Which makes the dealer's dilemna after accepting cash payment their problem, not the buyer's. The buyer with the ability to buy outright or get their own low-interest financing from their own institution without paying extra points or fees to pad the dealer's pocket with post-sale income should be rewarded for their intelligence and hard work. The entire approach of setting a price intending for the "real" price, which the buyer obviously still pays, to be higher, is deceitful. I say congratulations to the smart young buyers.

Comment: @Craig, yep. Totally.

Comment: Can we get an update on this?  I'm curious how things panned out.

Comment: @maria palmer -  So exactly what happened?

Answer (score 151):

Let me get this straight.

- Your son went to a car dealer
- Your son negotiated a price
- Everybody signed paperwork
- Your son then went to the bank with the paperwork and got a cashiers check.
- Your son delivered the check to the dealership
- Everybody signed more paperwork
- Your son drove away with the car
- Now two days later they want more money.

I would stand my ground. Your son negotiated in good faith. Either they messed up, or they are dishonest. Either way your son wasn't the one supposed to know all the internal rules.

I don't think it matters if they cashed the check or not. I would tell them if they have cashed it, that is even more evidence the deal was finalized. But even if they they didn't cash it, it only proves they are very disorganized.

If for some reason your son feels forced to redo the deal, have him start the negotiations way below the price that was agreed to.  If the deal for some strange reason gets voided don't let him agree to some sort of restocking fee.

Comment: This is a great answer and hits pretty much all the imaginable points. The car dealer messed up and are now attempting to negotiate in bad faith.

Comment: Part of the answer is that the error wasn't large enough to negate the deal. e.g. if the son were sold a car based on a typo, and charged $3000 for a $30000 car, we might be having a different conversation. A reasonable person wouldn't notice the discount wasn't 'correct', as it was probably just a few percent of the price. If the dealer continues, the OP should tell them they are harassing her and she will sue them.

Comment: I would also add, don't be emotionally attached to the car. Your son's position should be if they don't accept the deal as negotiated, he returns the car and they return the check, at no cost to him. The dealer needs the sale a lot more than your son needs this particular car.

Comment: Why shouldn't his son's position be the deal is already concluded, and it doesn't matter to him whether the dealer regrets it or not?

Comment: Sounds to me like they want to repurchase the car. If anything his son should ask extra money and find a different dealer, or just keep the car. As I get the feeling here the dealer just found a different customer that's willing to give a better price for the car, so he want it back (or at least the difference made up), and came up with this BS reason.

Comment: "he returns the car and they return the check" - Why? The transaction is concluded.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I think this is an example of a worst case scenario for the son.  Ie. the son need not worry about a confrontation here because the worst possible outcome is that they return the check and he returns the car - which is a minor inconvenience for the son and a lost sale for the dealer.

Comment: @Taemyr - understood. Still I disagree with Keith's comment and suggestion that " if they don't accept the deal as negotiated". There's nothing to accept. It's over.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer It depends a bit on circumstances.  If the paperwork is not finalised it might be easier to just walk away/threathen to walk away than to force the dealer to finish his work. - Even if OP is in the right.  I agree that offering to negate the sale is not the best opening move though.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I think my comment was a bit unclear, and I meant it in the way Taemyr suggested. If the transaction is complete, I agree that there is nothing to be done. What I suggested was meant to be a fallback in case the dealer starts being aggressive and the son just wants it to go away.

Comment: 1. I see the purchase as a contract. They can only request to renegotiate if so. 
2. If their financing did not have early payment penalties, it could be done and paid off with the first invoice. I made sure my recent car loan had that and am paying it off at triple the rate.

Same thing happened to my hubby when he bought his new truck. The dealer called the purchasing agent we go through for new vehicles and complained that they lost money on the deal. They wanted more. The agent said good for my customer and ended the call. I'm no lawyer and laws vary by state.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Money changed hands, in the eyes of the state and federal government, wherever you may be, the son owns the car. The title was passed over to him and signed by the dealership. No more action is required. In accordance with what @JoeTaxpayer said, if they continue to try to get more money on a sale that has been finalized, I would first contact the BBB.

Comment: @Taemyr I'd think the paper work is finalized when everyone that needs to signs the documents required to complete the sale, which would be the sales person and the OP's son.

Comment: I'm not an expert in US law, but can someone comment on whether the quote itself is also legally binding?

Comment: @RobertGrant: what quote?

Comment: I'm assuming that when they agreed a price a quotation was printed out; could be wrong I suppose.

Comment: When everybody signed the form and the purchaser went to the bank to get the cashiers check contract law would now apply. There was probably a deposit left with the dealer.

Comment: @RobertGrant Probably not, but the dealer signed the car over to the son, presumably, in exchange for money. Unless there is a caveat, or the son signed something else, the dealer really has no right to ask more money and has no power. The only reason the son should try to resolve this is if he got a warranty through the dealership. But it sounds like the son owns the car in full, so the dealership is trying to do something illegal.

Answer (score 48):

I had a similar situation when I was in college. The difference was that the dealer agreed to finance and the bank they used wanted a higher interest rate from me because of my limited credit history. The dealer asked for a rate 5 percentage points higher than what they put on the paperwork. I told them that I would not pay that and I dropped the car off at the lot with a letter rescinding the sale. They weren't happy about that and eventually offered me financing at my original rate with a $1000 discount from the previously agreed-upon purchase price. What I learned through that experience is that I didn't do a good-enough job of negotiating the original price.

I would suggest that your son stop answering phone calls from the dealership for at least 1 week and drive the car as much as possible in that time. If the dealer has cashed the check then that will be the end of it. He owes nothing further. If the dealer has not cashed the check, he should ask whether they prefer to keep the check or if they want the car with 1000 miles on the odometer. This only works if your son keeps his nerve and is willing to walk away from the car.

Comment: Uber perhaps..?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I wish you could have seen the big smile on my face when I read your comment. That's economic poetry.

Comment: I'm puzzled and worried about why this isn't the most upvoted answer, instead of one that says "well you might have to give it back" and another one saying "write a bad review". I mean, come on!

Comment: Have a friend with similar circumstance: New car, 0% financing, got the car on Saturday... Monday the bank said "not enough credit". Dealer then had to say "We can't give you 0%". Friend was able to drop the car off and basically ended up with a free car for the weekend. Sometimes it's not the dealer that causes this, but the bank. Dealer wanted the sale, friend wanted the car at 0%...

Comment: Well, attempting to extract as much value from the car when foreseeing return is acting with ill intent.

Comment: @Agent_L - The objective is to keep the car under the original terms negotiated.

Comment: @NathanL This is your objective - but you're achieving it by decreasing value of an item which ownership is under dispute.

Comment: @Agent_L - Illegitimate dispute. The buyer negotiated in good faith. The dealer is not acting in good faith if they are trying to extract more money from the buyer after the sale has closed and payment has been provided in full.

Comment: @NathanL You're mixing things up. The fact that it was bought in good faith **then** does not change the fact that you're encouraging to act with ill intent **now**. Defending a deal that's closed is one thing. Deprecating value of the item is another. It's not something that can get you arrested, but if this ever ends up in some kind of dispute resolution, it can be exploited and twisted to show buyer's ill intent. Buyer is squeaky clean here, going for dirt can do more harm than good. Plus, it only works for a new car.

Comment: Perhaps a better suggestion is _use the vehicle as if there is no dispute_. By that I mean, do not use it any less because the dealer is messing you around.

Comment: Specifically, if the dealer wants you to use the car less because its ownership is in dispute, then there's a thing called a "preliminary injunction" which the law provides in order to achieve that, where such restrictions are believed merited by the court. Good luck to them getting one.

Comment: Intentionally depreciating the value of the car just to worsen the position of the dealer? That is what I would call "being a jerk," regardless of who's right or wrong. Not to mention that it's not sound management of assets; you're decreasing its net worth to *yourself* even if you get to keep it.

Comment: @jpmc26 - The decrease in the asset's value is asymmetric as far as the buyer and the dealer are concerned. The buyer isn't going to have as much of a decrease in the value with respect to the price he can get from a third party since he has already driven it off the lot. The dealer however has a hard time positioning it as new when the odometer reading goes above 1000. Someone else might consider a dealer running a yo yo scam the person who is "being a jerk". Look it up, this is a textbook example. This is my final response to anyone who believes my suggestion is unethical.

Comment: @jpmc26 The car is his, he can do whatever he wants with it, and now you also call him a jerk? Seriously?

Comment: @Lohoris The dealer may be disputing his ownership due to this mistake. Regardless, yes, when you do something with the primary motivation of worsening the situation of other people, yes, that is being a jerk. The other group's behavior is irrelevant in that determination.

Comment: @jpmc26 totally not irrelevant, instead. But this is getting into the philosophy domain…

Answer (score 44):

> I'm sorry to hear you've made a mistake. Having read the contract of sale we signed, I do not see any remedy to your current situation.  However, I'm interested in making sure I do not take advantage of you.  As such, I'll return the vehicle, you can return my money plus the bank fees I paid for the cashiers check, tax, title, and registration, and I will look at buying a vehicle from another dealership.
>
> This seems to be the most fair resolution.  If I were to pay for your mistake at a price I did not agree to, it would not be fair to me.  If you were to allow this vehicle to go to me at the price we agreed to, it wouldn't be fair to you.  If I were to return the car and begin negotiations again, or find a different car in your lot, it would be difficult for us to know that you were not going to make a similar mistake again.
>
> At this point I consider the sale final, but if you'd prefer to have the vehicle back as-is, returning to us the money we gave you as well as the additional costs incurred by the sale, then we will do so in order to set things right.

Chances are good you will see them back down.  Perhaps they will just cut the additional payment in half, and say, "Well, it's our mistake, so we will eat half the cost," or similar, but this is merely another way to get you to pay more money.

Stand firm.  *"I appreciate the thought, but I cannot accept that offer. When will you have payment ready so we can return the car?"*

If you are firm that the only two solutions is to keep the car, or return it for a full refund plus associated costs, I'd guess they'd rather you keep the car - trust me, they still made a profit - but if they decide to have it returned, do so and make sure they pay you in full plus other costs.  Bring all your receipts, etc and don't hand over the keys until you have the check in hand.

Then go, gladly, to another dealership that doesn't abuse its customers so badly.

If you do end up keeping the car, don't plan on going back to that dealership.  Use another dealership for warranty work, and find a good mechanic for non-warranty work.

Note that this solution isn't legally required in most jurisdictions. Read your contract and all documentation they provided at the time of sale to be sure, but it's unlikely that you are legally required to make another payment for a vehicle after the sale is finalized.  Even if they haven't cashed the check, the sale has already been finalized.

What this solution does, though, is put you back in the driver's seat in negotiating.  Right now they are treating it as though you owe them something, and thus you might feel an obligation toward them.  Re-asserting your relationship with them as a customer rather than a debtor is very important regardless of how you proceed. You aren't legally culpable, and so making sure they understand you aren't will ultimately help you.

Further, dealerships operate on negotiation. The primary power the customer has in the dealership is the power to walk away from a deal.

They've set the situation up as though you no longer have the power to walk away.  They didn't threaten with re-possession because they can't - the sale is final. They presented as a one-path situation - you pay.  Period.

You do have many options, though, and they are very familiar with the "walk away" option.  Present that as your chosen option - either they stick with the original deal, or you walk away - and they will have to look at getting another car off the lot (which is often more important than making a profit for a dealership) or selling a slightly used car. If they've correctly pushed the title transfer through (or you, if that's your task in your state) then your brief ownership will show up on carfax and similar reports, and instantly reduces the car's worth.  Having the title transfer immediately back to the dealership doesn't look good to future buyers.

So the dealership doesn't want the car back.  They are just trying to extract more money, and probably illegally, depending on the laws in your jurisdiction.

Reassert your position as customer, and decide now that you'll be fine if you have to return it and walk away. Then when you communicate that to them, chances are good they'll simply cave and let the sale stand as-is.

Comment: Just as an added note, don't return the car until the money has been returned in full.  Make sure that you verify with your bank, that the dealership can't do the banking equivalent of a charge back.  Also make sure that you document in writing exactly what has happened.

Comment: "What this solution does, though, is put you back in the driver's seat in negotiating." Literally.

Comment: I was formulating an answer in my head when I saw you'd covered everything I was going to say.

Comment: When has a car dealer ever agreed to "undo" a deal due to a misunderstanding or mistake on the part of the buyer? Cars sales have always been final, final, final. Dealers reap what they sow.

Comment: One further warning, if the vehicle is being returned, title transfer should be dependent upon the dealer cheque clearing. They have been known not to clear. Usually for trade-ins.

Comment: I disagree this is a fair solution, why would he have to offer the car back? Now he needs to find a new car that he likes and go through all that trouble again.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I agree: this is a way to build a bargaining position. It won't work in all situations, but it's a less confrontational option to get the dealership to stop bothering them. Personally it would depend strongly on the type of relationship I wanted to have with the dealership in the future.  If I felt I'd have to go back to them later for maintenance or otherwise, I'd want to at least attempt to smooth things over. If not, I'd probably just tell them to sue me if they feel there's been a breach of contract.

Comment: One point: " If you were to allow this vehicle to go to me at the price we agreed to, it wouldn't be fair to you." - this is not true. They did the paperwork, and can be referred to the correct legal principle of _No backsies_.

Comment: @AdamDavis fair enough, but that doesn't make that statement correct; nor should they say it. They've made a mistake, and that's it. In the context of that the purchaser can decide to do what the dealership wants, but why hand them that statement?

Comment: @AdamDavis you're fixating a little on the _absoluteness_ of my statement, when your statement is just as absolute. You're saying it definitely _isn't_ fair. From my reading of what happened, there's no way it's not fair; from yours, it's 100% not fair. You're not occupying a middle ground here, and it's disingenuous to suggest otherwise. But I've followed you as far as I care to down the rabbit hole of arguing about the argument, rather than the subject, so I'll stop here :) The original matter is probably concluded either way.

Comment: @AdamDavis I totally understand the point of your answer. I was just contesting your claim that my stance - the situation is fair - is absolute, whereas your stance - the situation isn't fair - is not absolute. It's best not to slip on to claim yet another thing (that I don't understand you)  rather than discuss the points being made about your previous claim (that I was being absolute and you weren't), or just to call it quits without slipping anything in at all.

Answer (score 31):

The sales manager and/or finance manager applied a rebate that did not apply.

It's their fault.

They have internal accounts to handle these situations as they do come up from time to time.

The deal is done.

They have no legal ground.

Answer (score 24):

I have one additional recommendation: if the dealer continues to press the issue, tell them that they need to drop it, or you will write a Yelp review in excruciating detail about the entire experience.

Used car dealers are very aware of their Yelp presence and don't like to see recent, negative reviews because it can cost them a lot of new business.

(I'm assuming this is a used car. If it's a new car, you could go over their heads and bring up the problem with the manufacturer. Dealers hate it when you go directly to the manufacturer with a dealer complaint.)

Comment: The restrictions on the discount are likely imposed by the manufacturer. It's not clear to me how the manufacturer would respond to a dealer attempting to correct an error in complying with the terms for granting a discount.

Comment: @Eric It's still deeply unprofessional and affects their reputation. The manufacturer's ideal outcome is that the dealer is stuck with the cost out of their (dealer's) own pocket, since it was their mistake.

Comment: @Rocky: I'm not a lawyer, but isn't there a risk of this "accept the previous terms or I'll write a review" being seen as extortion? For that reason alone, I'd be cautious of attaching negative consequences.

Comment: That's more blackmail, really

Comment: @Random832 I think it depends on the level of harrassment.  The manufacturer will not be pleased with a dealer that ignores the rules on discounts.  A token effort to correct what may have been an honest mistake on dealer's side may be appreciated by the manufacturer to demonstrate the dealer's willingness to comply with the rules.

Comment: I don't think dealerships are fazed by the threat of 'bad review on social media'.

Comment: @Eric I assume the rules are for when the manufacturer pays for the discount. The dealer covering the difference out of their own pocket doesn't matter for that.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce: just give them a friendly reminder that Yelp reviews are a thing, that you were always planning to write one, and that you're going to stick to a factual report on the experience you had with the dealer regarding this transaction.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: This is a really nice dealership you have here. It'd be a shame if someone started writing bad reviews of it...

Comment: @Eric the restrictions on the discount are more likely imposed by the finance department who make tons of money off of financed purchases. "[Financial results for the six publicly traded, new-car dealer groups in the United States show that to a great extent, dealerships are in the business of selling new and used cars so they can service them and finance them.](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jimhenry/2012/02/29/the-surprising-ways-car-dealers-make-the-most-money-off-of-you/)"

Comment: @DA. Maybe they aren't, but they definitely *should* be. My wife was in the market for a new (well, used, new to her) car a couple years ago, and was actually willing to spend a couple thousand dollars more than she originally planned to spend, to buy a car from one specific used car dealership that had particularly good reviews indicating its unusually high trustworthiness. You'd *think* they would all want that - it's not like there aren't generally plenty of choices when it comes to car dealerships.

Comment: @neminem oh, I agree. In general, businesses *should* care about customer experience. I have yet to find a car dealership that does, though. Sigh. :)

Comment: @DA: I don't think anyone's claiming they care about customer experience, merely that they might care about their published reviews...

Comment: @AndrewCoonce You would never extort or blackmail the dealer by making "do this or else" statements. As another commenter said, you were planning to write a Yelp review anyway. You love Yelp. And now you're so upset that you feel a responsibility to warn other people about your bad experience. But mean it, and if they try to talk you out of it and back away from pushing the bad deal on you, great. Trust me, good Yelp reviews are gold, and bad ones are cancer, and they know it. But again, no extortion, no blackmail, but an honest review (just the facts, m'am) about your crappy experience.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce I see what you mean, except the point of Yelp reviews is to document such experiences. Threatening criminal damage (be a shame if anything happened to your dealership) isn't the same as threatening to expose them on a review service by writing the truth about your experience.

Answer (score 11):

Don't take the car back! The dealership wants you to take it back to try and earn more money. Simply stated, the dealerships hate paid up front cash deals. They make money on the financing. So to call back and try to up their fee is them realizing their not making a large enough profit. Say thank you and move on. The deal is done!!

Answer (score 8):

On the surface this sounds ridiculous, which makes me suspect that there might be something that the dealer intends to cling on to; otherwise it sounds like the dealer should be ashamed to even call your son about its own incompetence.

I'd recommend **politely** refusing the request since said mistake didn't happen on your end, and wait to see if the dealer comes back with some sort of argument.

Comment: Refusing might create problems with warranty later, if there is such a thin in the OP's country.

Comment: Assuming the deal is complete, it won't create any *legal* problem with the warranty.  It might create a *practical* problem with the warranty if the car needs to be serviced at the same dealership (or it's problematic to bring the car to some other authorized service shop), as they may take other steps to make life difficult that aren't strictly illegal (or at least obviously provably illegal).

Answer (score 7):

I've been an F&I Manager at a new car dealership for over ten years, and I can tell you this with absolute certainty, your deal is final. There is no legal obligation for you whatsoever. I see this post is a few weeks old so I am sure by now you already know this to be true, but for future reference in case someone in a similar situation comes across this thread, they too will know.

This is a completely different situation to the ones referenced earlier in the comments on being called by the dealer to return the vehicle due to the bank not buying the loan. That only pertains to customers who finance, the dealer is protected there because on isolated occasions, which the dealer hates as much as the customer, trust me, you are approved on contingency that the financing bank will approve your loan. That is an educated guess the finance manager makes based on credit history and past experience with the bank, which he is usually correct on. However there are times, especially late afternoon on Fridays when banks are preparing to close for the weekend the loan officer may not be able to approve you before closing time, in which case the dealer allows you to take the vehicle home until business is back up and running the following Monday. He does this mostly to give you sense of ownership, so you don't go down the street to the next dealership and go home in one of their vehicles.

However, there are those few instances for whatever reason the bank decides your credit just isn't strong enough for the rate agreed upon, so the dealer will try everything he can to either change to a different lender, or sell the loan at a higher rate which he has to get you to agree upon. If neither of those two things work, he will request that you return the car. Between the time you sign and the moment a lender agrees to purchase your contract the dealer is the lien holder, and has legal rights to repossession, in all 50 states. Not to mention you will sign a contingency contract before leaving that states you are not yet the owner of the car, probably not in so many simple words though, but it will certainly be in there before they let you take a car before the finalizing contract is signed.

Now as far as the situation of the OP, you purchased your car for cash, all documents signed, the car is yours, plain and simple. It doesn't matter what state you are in, if he's cashed the check, whatever. The buyer and seller both signed all documents stating a free and clear transaction. Your business is done in the eyes of the law. Most likely the salesman or finance manager who signed paperwork with you, noticed the error and was hoping to recoup the losses from a young novice buyer.

Regardless of the situation, it is extremely unprofessional, and clearly shows that this person is very inexperienced and reflects poorly on management as well for not doing a better job of training their employees. When I started out, I found myself in somewhat similar situations, both times I offered to pay the difference of my mistake, or deduct it from my part of the sale. The General Manager didn't take me up on my offer. He just told me we all make mistakes and to just learn from it. Had I been so unprofessional to call the customer and try to renegotiate terms, I would have without a doubt been fired on the spot.

Comment: please edit this wall of text. Paragraphs help readability.

Comment: One thing that I didn't mention in my answer about the financing debacle was that the dealer called me 3 weeks later, not the following Monday.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, if the dealer accepted payment and signed over ownership of the vehicle, that's a completed transaction. While there may or may not be a "cooling-off period" in your local laws, those protect the purchaser, not (as far as I know) the seller.

The auto dealer could have avoided this by selling for a fixed price. Instead, they chose to negotiate every sale. Having done so, it's entirely their responsibility to check that they are happy with their final agreement. Failing to do so is going to cost someone their commission on the sale, but that's not the buyer's responsibility. They certainly wouldn't let you off the hook if the final price was higher than you had previously agreed to.

He who lives by the fine print shall die by the fine print. This is one of the reasons there is huge turnover in auto sales staff; few of them are really good at the job.

If you want to be kind to the guy you could give him the chance to sell you something else. Or perhaps even offer him a $100 tip. But assuming the description is correct, and assuming local law doesn't say otherwise (***if in any doubt, ask a lawyer!!!***), I don't think you have any remaining obligation toward them

On the other hand, depending on how they react to this statement, you might want to avoid their service department, just in case someone is unreasonably stupid and tries to make up the difference that was.

Comment: I wouldn't offer a tip to the salesman at this point. That might serve to substantiate the notion (however false) that the buyer did something wrong and feels morally/ethically compelled to pay for it. The dealer knows their own costs and their own arrangements with the manufacturers. If the dealership can only make money on a sale if they get the additional interest, or a kickback, from the financing, it's their responsibility to both know that during negotiations and to be honest about it *so the buyer fully understands they are in fact paying the dealer more than the negotiated price."

Comment: Valid point, @craig; it's a judgement call based on how much sympathy you feel for the salesman who screwed himself out of a commission. I grant that nobody, including me, feels a lot of sympathy for most car salesmen. Just tossing it out as a thought to use or ignore as one sees fit.

Comment: I totally get that, and have no issue at all with the sentiment.  ;-)  It's just that actually handing over a tip in the form of cash to "make up" for the situation has at least the marginal potential to provide the dealership (not even the salesman) a legal argument that could result in real financial action. Kind of unfortunate, maybe, but that's why I wouldn't touch it.

Comment: We agree that we disagree. I am not a lawyer.

Comment: I am *not* disagreeing. I like your sentiment. I am urging caution and saying that I personally would err on the side of not handing ammunition to an enemy holding a gun, that's all.  ;-) If you feel an emotional need to pay the $100 tip, I *would* consult an attorney first to make sure you can't hurt yourself by doing so.

Comment: "Live by the fine print, die by the fine print."

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at it this way. Your son bought the car and then 2 days later, he wants to change the price. Will the dealership let him do that after all the paperwork is signed?

Comment: They might, if, for example, he found out he was eligible for an advertised manufacturer's incentive discount that he was not given.

Answer (score 0):

As mhoran_psprep and others have already said, it sounds like the sale is concluded and your son has no obligation to return the car or pay a dime more. The only case in which your son should consider returning the car is if it works in his favor--for example, if he is able to secure a similar bargain on a different car and the current dealer buys the current car back from your son at a loss.

If the dealer wants to buy the car back, your son should first get them to agree to cover any fees already incurred by your son. After that, he should negotiate that the dealer split the remaining difference with him.

Suppose the dealership gave a $3000 discount, and your son paid $1000 in title transfer, registration, and any other fees such as a cashier's check or tax, if applicable. The remaining difference is $2000. Your son should get half that.  In this scenario, the dealer only loses half as much money, and your son gains $1000 for his trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Your son is in the right. But he broke the "unwritten" rules, which is why the car dealer is upset.

Basically, cars are sold in the United States at a breakeven price. The car company makes ALL its money on the financing. If everyone bought "all cash," the car companies would not be profitable.

No one expected anyone, least of all your son, a "young person," to pay "all cash." When he did, they lost all the profit on the deal.

On the other hand, they signed a contract, your son met all the FORMAL requirements, and if there was an "understanding" (an assumption, actually), that the car was supposed to be financed, your son was not part of it.

Good for him. And if necessary, you should be prepared to back him up on court.

Comment: This is partially true, but buyers go to the dealership with a check all the time, many just getting their financing from somewhere other than the dealer. The dealership doesn't know if the son used cash from a savings account or a loan. (For that matter, neither do we.)

Comment: Dealers actually make their money on rebates and incentives and by reselling trade-ins at a profit, not just on financing.

Comment: @rob Don't forget screwing people with ridiculous prices for poorly done service at book rates.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller Oh, how could I forget that one!? It isn't just dealers, either. I know the book rates are supposed to even out the cost of fast jobs vs. long jobs, but when I take my car in for a supposedly 10-hour job (by the book) and they haven't even started working on it at 5 PM, but they call me an hour and a half later to say it's done, that's just wrong to charge 10 hours anyway.

Comment: If they quoted him a price, weren't willing to sell the car at that price, and didn't mention that, they were negotiating in bad faith. They need to have this happen to them as many times as it takes for them to stop doing that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:I agree. That's why I told the father to "back him up in court" if necessary.

Answer (score -2):

If the discount is only for financed car then their software application should have accepted the payment (electronic transfer ID) from financed bank. In this case the bank should have given the payment on behalf of your son.

I believe the dealer know in advance about the paper work and deal they were doing with your son. Financing a car is a big process between dealer and bank.

Comment: The dealer's argument is that the discount only applies when you use the dealer's own financing option. Whether or not the purchaser used his own money or borrowed it from a third party doesn't matter to the dealer; either way, they got cash.

Comment: @BenMiller The dealer did get cash, but they may also get money from the manufacturer to cover the discount if the sale was financed through the dealer.

Comment: More likely a (trailing ?) commission from the true finance provider. Which they are shaving for the offered price, no commission at all means less profit.